# Bundle Python package to a single file

Tags: python, bundle

I'm in a system where I cannot install any package nor create files/directories, exec shell commands, even from Python, and I don't have anything but Python installed.

I can ONLY copy-paste some code at the top of my script.

I would like to use X library, so I was thinking if there is any way to bundle the library, like in JavaScript, getting all the exports in the global scope, copy-pasting the bundle in my file so I can use them in my code.

Comment: if you have all modules in one folder then you could add this folder to list `sys.path` at the beginning of your script and `import` should find them.

Comment: Read the first line please, "I'm in a system where I cannot install any package nor create files/directories."

Comment: I don't know method to put all code in one file. Some modules may use many files and folders so it would be big challenge to put all in one file. Maybe you could run your script on external server - like [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)

Comment: In this case, it must be run on a custom server. Yeah, it would be a big challenge to put it all in one file, that's what a bundler does.

Comment: tools like [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) put all code in one executable file (ie `.exe` on Windows) but it is self-extracting `.zip` file which always creates temporary folder and uncompress all files to this folder and run code - so it will not work if you can't create files/folders.

Comment: Pathfinding is a very simple library, you should be able to just go through and copy-paste the pieces you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [`pinliner`](https://github.com/Akrog/pinliner) do what you need?

> This tool allows you to merge all files that comprise a Python package into a single file and be able to use this single file as if it were a package.